# How can I use a variable that could potentially be a string in a mathematical sum in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my current code. I'm trying to create a code that'll take a number, `n` (here I called it nombres) and ask for "n" numbers. Those numbers will then be added to one another. If, however, the input is negative, the program will ask for an infinity of numbers **until** the user inputs "F" instead of another number.
What am I doing wrong?

```
nombres = int(input())
somme = 0

if nombres > 0:
    for i in range(nombres):
        while nombres > 0:
            n = int(input())
            nombres = nombres - 1
            somme = somme + n

else:
    if nombres != 'F':
        n = int(input())
        somme = somme + n

print(somme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a nested loop here

```
if nombres > 0:
    for i in range(nombres):
        while nombres > 0:
            n = int(input())
            nombres = nombres - 1
            somme = somme + n
```

the for loop makes it run n times and so does the while loop, so you end up n^2 iterations.

Furthermore, the condition `if nombres != 'F':` is not what you wanted, You want to check if the infput after the first one is F not the initial input.

Answer (score 0):

```
if nombres > 0:
    for i in range(nombres):
        while nombres > 0:
            n = int(input())
            nombres = nombres - 1
            somme = somme + n
```

There are 2 nested loops, you have to remove one of them.

```
if nombres > 0:
    for i in range(nombres):
        n = int(input())
        somme = somme + n
```

Or

```
if nombres > 0:
    while nombres > 0:
        n = int(input())
        nombres = nombres - 1
        somme = somme + n
```

In the `else` blck, the code should be like this:

```
else:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            somme = somme + n
```